# Try to call create event using graph api with isOnlineMeeting false for MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Getting isOnlineMeeting false while send isOnlineMeeting true whe we create the event using Graph API.

Answer (score 1):

Could not reproduce the issue while creating a calendar event using Graph API. Kindly confirm if you are able to still reproduce it on your end.

Used the below query to create a new event:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{id}/events
```

Request Body:

```
{
"subject": "Test Create Event",
"IsOnlineMeeting": "True",
"onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness",
"body": {
"contentType": "HTML",
"content": "Does this time work for you?"
},
"start": {
"dateTime": "2020-12-18T12:00:00",
"timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
},
"end": {
"dateTime": "2020-12-18T14:00:00",
"timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
},
"location": {
"displayName": "Conf Room 1"
},
"attendees": [
{
"emailAddress": {
"address": "abc@mxxxxxxx.com",
"name": "Someone"
},
"type": "required"
}
]
}
```

Outcome: Was able to create a new calendar event with IsOnlineMeeting value set to true.

In case you are trying to update an existing calendar event, there is a known issue in that, where the isOnlineMeeting value keeps toggling between true and false for each update/patch request.
In that case, do not update the body in the request, and it should work.
There is an open bug for the update event issue.

Please refer -> [Microsoft team link is not appearing for alternate update calendar events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65320427/microsoft-team-link-is-not-appearing-for-alternate-update-calendar-events)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, I add to add these permissions to the app I was using to create the meeting events:

TeamSettings.Read.All, TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All

As soon as I added them, isOnlineMeeting was correctly set to true, and onlineMeetingProvider was set to teamsForBusiness, as specified in the request.

onlineMeetingUrl is always null, but it's possible to get the meeting url from the "onlineMeeting.joinUrl" property, which is automatically populated by the API.