# Microsoft team link is not appearing for alternate update calendar events

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am using Microsoft graph API to create and update calendar events.

While creating an event with Teams selected, a calendar event will be created and an email got sent with team link but on updating the same event, team link is missing in email.

Like that for alternate update events team link is missing

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

To keep the meeting link, do not update the body in the request, and it should work.

The issue is happening because of a fix / feature that has been implemented on outlook end where it is cleaning up the online meeting properties if the teams meeting blob is removed from the body.
Please try the same after removing body in the request. The isOnlineMeeting value will not toggle. Hence the link will remain.

Please refer -> https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/10618

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27859103)

Comment: Thank you for reviewing my answer. I will be keeping this in mind in my later posts while answering here. I have updated the answer correctly. Hope that is fine.

Comment: Checked internally and there is an active bug on the same issue.

Comment: Thank you @Mallipriya-MSFT for confirming the same.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have tested by removing the body and it worked. But in our case we are passing an agenda as part of the meeting content. So that won't work when we remove the body. So actually is this a new feature of graph api or is it somewhat like a bug?

Comment: With repetitive update of meeting with change in subject alone instead of altering body using Events API PATCH request, similar incorrect behavior was observed. Team is investigating on this with bug raised.